# What does it mean for a Banach space to be $1$-complementable?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, terminology, banach-spaces

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/393982) the author mentions the concept of $1$-complementability as an example of a property of Banach spaces that is not preserved under (non-isometric) isomorphisms.

I couldn't find any information about this notion anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We say that a closed subspace $Y$ of a Banach space is $\lambda$-complemented, if there exists a linear projection $P:X\to Y$ with $\|P\| \leq \lambda$. In particular, it's $1$-complemented if there exists a projection onto $Y$ of norm $1$.

Reference: Definition 4.1 in *Banach Space Theory: The basis for linear and nonlinear analysis* by Fabian, Habala, Hájek, Montesinos and Zizler